# Google Docs Table Cells Suddenly Don't Word-Wrap When Editing

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

Step by step, here's what is happening:

I have hundred of Word documents that I created in Microsoft Word, WPS Office, and Google Docs, all of which contain tables that originally had word-wrapping.

Example:
[image: Table with word-wrapping in WPS]

And yet, as of this morning, all of these documents have suddenly lost their word wrapping when I try to edit them in Google Docs:

[image: Lost word-wrapping when editing in Google Docs]

Still, they all appear normal when I use preview mode in Docs rather than trying to edit them:

[image]

The problem: I need them to appear normal when editing them in Google Docs -- like they have for the past several years up until this morning.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Additional info:
Nothing in the Google Docs support documentation works. While Google Sheets has a word-wrap option for table cells, Google Docs doesn't seem to have this -- it has always just been the case that word-wrapping has been the default.

**Update:** This is only happening when I use Google Docs via Google Chrome (hence the adding of the google-chrome tag to my question). There is no problem when using Firefox. I will check my Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by 'Adblock Plus - free ad blocker' Chrome extension, Version 3.10.2